# How to escape "\" from JSON string in Titanium?

Tags: json, titanium, titanium-modules

I have written a native android module where i am returning Json string to JavaScript layer. But in javascript layer , i am getting this json string added with "\" for all "". How to escape this "\" from json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that your `json` is not a "real JSON object" but just a String. This explain why `"` symbol are escaped. Try to use `JSON.parse()` in your javascript.

```
var my_json_string = "{\"my_key\": \"the_value\"}";
var my_json_object = JSON.parse(my_json_string);
// should render something like 
// Object {my_key: "the_value"}
```